# How to aply mean_squared_error over a 3D array

Tags: python-2.7, nested-loops, mean-square-error

I am building a penalized regression model with 2 parameters $\lambda$ and $\alpha$. I am trying to find optimal values for these parameters so I consider a grid of different values. Let's say I consider `n_lambda` different $\lambda$ values and `n_alpha` different $\alpha$ values. In order to test the performance of the model, I consider $n$ data observations, for which I have the true value of my response vartiable, and I compute the predictions for these observations for each parameters pair.

I store my predictions into a 3D-array matrix with dimension `(n_lambda, n_alpha, n_observations)`. This means that element `[0, 0, :]` of this matrix contains the predictions for n observations for the first value of $\lambda$ and the first value of $\alpha$.

Now I want to compute, for each of my predictions, the means squared error. I know I can do this using nested for loops like:

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
error_matrix = np.zeros(n_lambda, n_alpha)
for i in range(n_lambda):
    for j in range(n_alpha):
        error_matrix[i, j] = mean_squared_error(true_value, prediction[i, j, :])
```

This would work, but nesting for loops is not really optimal. I guess there must be a better way to get what I want. Actually I have tried using `map` function but it is not working so I would appreciate any advice.